# How to call the function from server to client? (Remote Function Call)

Tags: javascript, http, client-server

Actually I want to do this;
A client registers a function to server through any user interfaces, then the server executes the function.

is it possible to call the function from server to client?

if possible, then cloud you share a best practice for this issue?

Thank you,
Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn't possible, at least not directly.

The client can make an HTTP request. The server side code can respond to that request in a way that tests the incoming data and calls a specific function in response to something about it.